# Would it be possible to make my Python App made using Eel a Website

Tags: python, python-webbrowser, eel

I just finished making an eel application and I really like the module since it allows you to communicate with Javascript while using Python. I know that eel hosts a local server and basically uses chrome to make it like an app but I want to be able to upload my files on a VPS. My app is like a social media bot that automates a couple of things by just providing a username. I want to host it as like a site so my friends could access it through a link rather than downloading my files or exe I can package. **(I DON'T WANT TO USE FLASK OR DJANGO)** I'm just looking if there is a way of hosting my eel project as a website or modules that do similar things.

**Eel**
https://github.com/samuelhwilliams/Eel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started).

After you have a `localhost` set up, you can host with:

```
$ ngrok http 8080
```

Replace `8080` with your `localhost` port

Then you will be given a WAN link to access your page's root directory. Make sure to append `/index.html` or whatever to be able to load into your page

> [`ngrok` getting started](https://ngrok.com/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score -1):

Run it locally and publish it online with ngrok.